# How to get data for the same time of the previous n days base on current time

Tags: pandas

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'time': ['2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-01-01 04:00:00', '2020-01-01 08:00:00', '2020-01-01 12:00:00', '2020-01-01 16:00:00', '2020-01-01 20:00:00', '2020-01-02 00:00:00', '2020-01-02 04:00:00', '2020-01-02 08:00:00', '2020-01-02 12:00:00', '2020-01-02 16:00:00', '2020-01-02 20:00:00', '2020-01-03 00:00:00', '2020-01-03 04:00:00', '2020-01-03 08:00:00', '2020-01-03 12:00:00', '2020-01-03 16:00:00', '2020-01-03 20:00:00', '2020-01-04 00:00:00', '2020-01-04 04:00:00'], 'category': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'], 'nums': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

[image]

---

i have a data like in the picture
i want to pd.groupby('category'),then get data for the same time of the previous n(n can be 1,2 ..and so on,we can suppose n=1)days base on current  time in  every group

if needn't group operation,i can get it by (data.rolling(window='1D',closed='both',on='time').apply(lambda x:x[0])) with pandas,but ,if groupy needed ,i don't know how to do

in conclusion,i want get it in every group. How can I do it?

Comment: we need text of input, not image. read following post: [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code**

```
# convert to datetime
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

# process
out = (
    df.set_index(['time', 'category'])
    .assign(
        prev=(
            df.set_index('time')
            .shift(freq='D')
            .set_index('category', append=True)
        )
    )
    .reset_index()
)
```

out

```
    time    category    nums    prev
0   2020-01-01 00:00:00 a   0   NaN
1   2020-01-01 04:00:00 a   1   NaN
2   2020-01-01 08:00:00 a   2   NaN
3   2020-01-01 12:00:00 a   3   NaN
4   2020-01-01 16:00:00 b   4   NaN
5   2020-01-01 20:00:00 b   5   NaN
6   2020-01-02 00:00:00 b   6   NaN
7   2020-01-02 04:00:00 b   7   NaN
8   2020-01-02 08:00:00 b   8   NaN
9   2020-01-02 12:00:00 b   9   NaN
10  2020-01-02 16:00:00 b   10  4.00
11  2020-01-02 20:00:00 b   11  5.00
12  2020-01-03 00:00:00 c   12  NaN
13  2020-01-03 04:00:00 c   13  NaN
14  2020-01-03 08:00:00 c   14  NaN
15  2020-01-03 12:00:00 c   15  NaN
16  2020-01-03 16:00:00 c   16  NaN
17  2020-01-03 20:00:00 c   17  NaN
18  2020-01-04 00:00:00 c   18  12.00
19  2020-01-04 04:00:00 c   19  13.00
```